# Overwriting default values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-value, for-in-loop, optional-arguments

I have a function which has a default configuration stored in an object. The function takes optional argument "options", if there is any configuration in the options argument, it should overwrite the default config.

This is my implementation:

```js
const myFunction = (props) => {
  const config = {
    slopeModifier: 2,
    minDistance: 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal: true,
    callback: null,
  };

  if (props.options) {
    for (const property in options) {
      config[property] = options[property];
    }
  }

};
export default myFunction;
```

in other file I would do something like this:

```js
import myFunction

const options = {minDistance: 50, slope: 3};
myFunction({arg1, arg2, options});
```

Is this solution a good practice? Is there a standard way how to store default values and overwrite them with optional argument?
Also, I am getting an *eslint(guard-for-in)* warning, could my code cause any bugs?

Comment: You get a `for-in` warning because of the reasons shown in the ESLint docs for that rule. It's verbose since you could just use destructuring or `Object.assign`. The pattern itself is very common.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a standard way how to store default values and overwrite them with optional argument?

Yes, there's a standard way to do this, via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const myFunction = (props) => {
  const config = Object.assign({
    slopeModifier: 2,
    minDistance: 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal: true,
    callback: null,
  }, props.options);

  // ...

};
export default myFunction;
```

There's also a newer [Rest/Spread syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) available, which [Alberto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59720190/120955) shows.

```
  const config = {
    slopeModifier: 2,
    minDistance: 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal: true,
    callback: null,
    ... props.options
  };
```

> Is this solution a good practice?

Overriding default config this way is fine. My concern would be with putting other arguments on your options object. If your other arguments are required, you might want to make them official parameters in their own right, and have the `options` be a last (optional) parameter.

```
const myFunction = (arg1, arg2, props) => ...;
```

```
const options = {minDistance: 50, slope: 3};
myFunction(arg1, arg2, options);
```

> Also, I am getting an eslint(guard-for-in) warning, could my code cause any bugs?

It could. As [the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in) point out, it's possible that someone could add properties to the `prototype` for whatever object type you pass in as your options, and you'd be picking up those prototype properties in addition to whatever properties were added directly to the object. This would be bad practice, but it's not unheard of:

```
// someone else's code, maybe in a third-party library that thought it was being clever.
Object.prototype.foo = "bar";

// Your code
for(const prop in {"1": 2}) { console.log(prop); }
```

Output:

> 1
> foo

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! If there were extra properties in options that are not in config, they would be added as well. Is there a solution that would not allow this (i.e. overwrite the values, but do not add any new keys)?

Comment: Not that I know of. In most cases, methods would ignore anything on `options` that aren't part of its intended input. If that's not the case for you, you could sanitize the resulting `options` object manually. `config = {slopeModifier: config.slopeModifier, ...};`

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function without any parameters and the default values will be applied:

```
const myFunction = ({
    slopeModifier = 2,
    minDistance = 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal = true,
    callback = null
  } = {}) => {
  ...
};

export default myFunction;
```

On your other file, you can call the function like this:

```
import myFunction

myFunction({minDistance: 10}); // or myFunction();
```

**Example**

```js
const myFunction = ({
    slopeModifier = 2,
    minDistance = 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal = true,
    callback = null
  } = {}) => {
  console.log(slopeModifier, minDistance);
};

myFunction();
myFunction({minDistance: 10});
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Can you show how the argument to `myFunction` would be accessed? It doesn't seem to have a name.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior sorry I've made a mistake. I've updated the code with a working example.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're using [this syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameters_default_value). I wasn't aware of that option.

Comment: Yes, exactly! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread operator to override properties if the `props.options` exist in the function call, like this:

```
const myFunction = (props) => {
  const config = {
    slopeModifier: 2,
    minDistance: 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal: true,
    callback: null,
    ...props.options
  };
};

export default myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and are better off creating a class to set, update, and return your config code:

```js
class configClass{
  
  config = {
    slopeModifier: 2,
    minDistance: 30,
    lockScrollIfHorizontal: true,
    callback: null
  }

  getConfig(){
      return this.config
  }
  
  updateConfig(options){
      for(const property in options) {
          this.config[property] = options[property]
      }
  }

}

//export default configClass 
//import configClass as myClass
const myClass = new configClass()

const options = {minDistance: 50, slope: 3}
const obj = {arg1:"foo", arg2:"bar", options: options}
myClass.updateConfig(obj.options)
console.log(myClass.getConfig())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```